# C# Timer firing too early

Tags: c#, timer, system.timers.timer

When I call the Method random_Start() it works at first: The second console print comes at a reasonable time, but then the gap between the console prints gets smaller and smaller.

After some prints, almost every print comes after way less than 5 Seconds, although the code should set a Timer for at least 5 Seconds, right?

```cs
        static Timer timer;
        static Random random = new Random();
        public static void random_Start()
        {
            timer = new Timer(random.NextDouble()*10000+5000);
            timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            timer.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Start");
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            random_Start();
        }
```

Comment: The issue is that when in OnTimedEvent delegate you call random_Start, new instances of the timer are created and assigned, it never stops.
You shouldn't be calling random_Start each time the timer elapses.

Comment: `random.NextDouble()*10000+5000` seems very odd. Why not just `random.Next(minValue, maxValue)`?

Comment: Indeed, to echo what rufus just said, if you want a number between 5000 and 15000 milliseconds it is far more readable to call `random.Next(5000, 15000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup your timer so that you aren't creating a new instance with every timer tick. In the example below, I've disabled `AutoReset` so that we can set a new interval and start the timer again manually.

```
    static Timer timer;
    static Random random = new Random();
    public static void random_Start()
    {
        timer = new Timer(random.NextDouble()*10000+5000);
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tick");
        timer.Interval = random.NextDouble()*10000+5000;
        timer.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Calling `Start` in the `Elapsed` event handler isn't necessary, since it would only get executed if the timer was already `Enabled`...